# How Can I verify 'Footer Top'(Web Element) background image colour?

Tags: list, selenium, for-loop, xpath, header

I am just trying to verifying color for 'footer-top' background image.

**Console view for 'footer top' icon is'**

*Under Styles:*

```
footer .footer-top {
    background: #1571c9;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 55px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    width: 100%;
```

*Under Elements:*

```
<div class="footer-top">
<div class="sw-layout">
<div class="footer-section">
<h5>More Information</h5>
<ul>
<li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-section hide-for-xs">
<h5>Finance Cards</h5>
<ul>
<div>
<li><a href="/finance-cards/cash-back-cards">Cash Back Finance Cards</a></li></div>
<li><a href="/finance-cards/points-rewards-cards">Points / Rewards Credit Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="/finance-cards/travel-air-miles-cards">Travel / Air Miles Credit Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="/finance-cards/islamic-cards">Islamic Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="/finance-cards/business-cards">Business Credit Cards</a></li>
</li>
</ul>
</div><div class="footer-section hide-for-xs">
<h5>Personal Loans</h5>
<ul>
<li><a href="salary-transfer-loans">Salary Transfer Loans</a></li>
<li><a href="loans-without-salary-transfer">Loans Without Salary Transfer</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**I am using below lines of code :**

```
  String FooterTopSectionColour =    
  driver.findElement(By.className("footer-top")).getCssValue("background");         
   try {    
         Assert.assertEquals("#1571c9", FooterTopSectionColour);
         System.out.println("Colour matches with : "+ 
         FooterTopSectionColour);
       } 
   catch (Error e) 
       {e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

In DOM colour is given in Hex value but Selenium is returning in terms of rgb. 
You can check below **error in console for the same** :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [rgb(21, 113, 201) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box] but found [#1571c9]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:190)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:200)
    at tests.homepage.HomePageStepDefinitions.vefify_colour_for_footer_top_section(HomePageStepDefinitions.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

So, How can I debug it? 
Please once check the code which I have used is correct or not!
And also let me know how to convert hex to rgb and compare it by using selenium? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what `System.out.println("Colour matches with : "+FooterTopSectionColour);` is printing by commenting that Assert condition?

Answer (score 1):

As your DOM colour and the CSS colours are different, you need to convert one format to to other and then you need to compare or assert it.

In the below code, I have added the steps which will convert the RGB values into an Hexa decimal and then assert the condition. And I assume that, if you print 'footerTopSelectionColour' value then it prints in the below format :

> rgb(21, 113, 201) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box
>   border-box

Find the modified lines of your code below :

```
String footerTopSectionColour = driver.findElement(By.className("footer-top")).getCssValue("background");
try {
    // I'm assuming that the value of 'footerTopSelectionColour' value will be like below
    // rgb(21, 113, 201) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box

    // So first we need to convert colour code from rgb to hexa decimal
    String value = footerTopSectionColour.trim();
    String[] rgbs = value.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].split(", ");
    long r = Long.parseLong(rgbs[0]);
    long g = Long.parseLong(rgbs[1]);
    long b = Long.parseLong(rgbs[2]);
    String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
    System.out.println("=> The hex conversion is : "+hex);

    // After converting you can assert like below
    Assert.assertEquals("#1571c9", hex);
    System.out.println("Colour matches with : "+ footerTopSectionColour);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this answer helps...

Comment: Above code is working fine in converting to hex value but assert condition is failed.

Comment: @Avinmita, there was some mistake while asserting the condition and now I have modified. Can you check now?

Comment: Yes I did the same. But I am hard-coding the value so in future, if there any change in the colour then this code doesn't work. right?

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals();` takes two values - first is an expected and the second is an actual value so to compare the actual result with an expected you need to provide expected from somewhere(Here you are hard coding and this is entirely depends on your implementation).

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Does selenium provide such method by that I can fetch hex value from DOM directly instead of getting converted rgb value?

Comment: No I guess but I'm not sure. I will let you know If I find something related to this

Answer (score 0):

Above ans is working fine in converting value from rgb to hexa but assert statement is failed.

**footerTopSectionColour colour is** : rgb(21, 113, 201) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box

**The hex conversion is** : #1571c9

> *Assert.assertEquals(hex, footerTopSectionColour);*

Above line of code is throwing error as it is comparing 2 dissimilar values. So instead , use below assert statement to verify it and it works fine.

> *Assert.assertEquals("#1571c9", hex);*